# Single Table Inheritance and 'type' value for namespaced classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, ruby-on-rails-2, single-table-inheritance, legacy-code

While working on Rails 2.3.18 to Rails 3.2.x migration I am facing name issue in `type` column

Here is the relation that is defined.

```
app/models/reservation.rb

class Reservation
end

class Reservation::Guest < Reservation
end

class Reservation::Event < Reservation
end
```

While saving `Reservation::Guest` Or `Reservation::Event` instance, the `type` value being saved is `Reservation::Guest` and `Reservation::Event` in Rails 3. But in Rails 2 it saves without namespace i.e., `Guest` or `Event`.

It requires lots of efforts to migrate existing data and change all the places which expects `type` without namespace.

Would it be possible to save `type` without namespace and rest work without making lots of modification across the application?

Comment: Did u tried aliasing the class name. something like this. `Guest = Reservation::Guest`, I don't think its best to change the type at runtime, as there might be many dependent things.

Comment: @AbibullahRahamathulah many things break by aliasing. So that would not be the solution.

Comment: @AmitPatel is this what you need?

Answer (score 28):

Take a look at [`sti_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods/sti_name) and [`find_sti_class`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_sti_class/class). (The methods responsible for setting and getting the sti_name)

---

You  can customize them as follows:

```
class Reservation
  def self.find_sti_class(type_name)
    type_name = self.name
    super
  end
end

class Reservation::Guest < Reservation
  def self.sti_name
    "Guest"
  end
end

class Reservation::Event < Reservation
  def self.sti_name
    "Event"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 18):

I know it's an old question, but maybe someone will use it.

Expanding on the answer by mohameddiaa27, the easiest way to get rid of namespace is to declare `store_full_sti_class`, since it's used by `sti_name`.

```
class Reservation

  # don't include namespace in type column
  def self.store_full_sti_class
    false
  end
end
```